# Hall's theorem problem for bipartite graph II - using hint

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(V_0,V_1,E)$ be a bipartite graph. Suppose $\deg v\geq 1$ for all
>   $v\in V_0$. Suppose moreover that whenever $v\in V_0,v^\prime\in V_1$
>   are adjacent, $\deg v\geq \deg v^\prime$. Prove there's a matching of
>   size $|V_0|$ in $G$.

**Hint.** Assume there's no such matching, and look at a minimal $U\subset V_0$ for which $|U|>|N(U)|$. Now use Hall's theorem on a set of the form $U\setminus \left\{ v \right\}$.

I tried to solve this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930446/halls-theorem-problem-for-bipartite-graph) but I think my method is bad and I didn't use the hint. My problem is that I don't see how a matching of $U\setminus \left\{ v \right\}$ would help.

**Later...** I think I understand, and this also mends the linked attempt.

Since $G$ is bipartite, we have for any $U\subset V_0$ $$\sum_{v\in U}\deg v\leq \sum_{v^\prime\in N(U)}\deg v^\prime.$$

Assume there's no matching and suppose $U$ is minimal such that $|U|>|N(U)|$. By minimality, there's a matching of the subgraph induced by $U\setminus \left\{ v \right\}= \left\{ v_1,\dots ,v_n \right\} $ and $ \left\{ u_1,\dots ,u_n \right\} \subset N(U\setminus \left\{ v \right\} )$. Hence, $\sum_i \deg v_i\geq \sum_i \deg u_i$ (because $\deg v_i\geq \deg u_i$).

Since $n+1=|U|>|N(U)|\geq n$, we have $|N(U)|=n$. Now using the matching we find $$\deg v+\sum_i\deg v_i>\sum_i\deg u_i$$ where the $>$ is because $\deg v\geq 1$.

Contradiction.

Is this okay?

Comment: @MorganRodgers is what I wrote correct?

Comment: It could be organized a little more clearly, but it appears to be okay.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I will make sure to organize it more clearly in the solution I submit